# Redirecting old sub domain to new Domain with alias parameter in URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, httpd.conf

I'm successful redirecting the old sub domain to new one
Here is the `httpd.conf`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName  abcd.com
   ServerAlias *.abcd.com
   RewriteEngine on
   Redirect 301 / http://pqr.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

The links like: `mumbai.abcd.com/venue/320089-girgaum-chowpatty` gets redirected to `http://pqr.com/venue/320089-girgaum-chowpatty`

But instead I would like to achieve: `http://pqr.com/mumbai/320089-girgaum-chowpatty`

Also just `mumbai.abcd.com` should redirect to `http://prq.com/mumbai`

I want to get the server alias and append in the url of new domain . How can I do that?

Comment: what about mod-rewrite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common place to define these redirects would be an `.htaccess` in your web root directory instead of `httpd.conf`, because it is much more flexible and does not require you to restart apache.

So I suggest you remove these lines from `httpd.conf`:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 / http://pqr.com/
```

And create an `.htaccess` file next to you root `index.php` with these contents:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect mumbai.abcd.com to prq.com/mumbai
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mumbai\.abcd\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://prq.com/mumbai/ [L,R=301]

# Redirect mumbai.abcd.com/something/123456-foo to prq.com/mumbai/123456-foo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mumbai\.abcd\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/]+)(/?)$ http://prq.com/mumbai/$2 [L,R=301]
```

If `mumbai.abcd.com` was just an example and you have more subdomains, try this:

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect *.abcd.com to prq.com/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.abcd\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://prq.com/%1/ [L,R=301]

# Redirect *.abcd.com/something/123456-foo to prq.com/*/123456-foo
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^/.]+)\.abcd\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([^/]+)(/?)$ http://prq.com/%1/$2 [L,R=301]
```